# jQuery POST form that is viewed with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ok, this is my first time logged in, but have a question which I can`t find. Maybe I used the wrong search terms or it is my broken English.
But hopefully, somebody can point me in the right direction.

My situation. I have a list of users. When I click on one of them a second screen opens using javascript/AJAX. Some CSS styling does the split screen thing.

In the second screen, I show a form with some info or not. So far so good.
What I want is that when you change some info and you press the submit/save button, data gets saved in the database without a page refresh. But I can't get it right. When I press the button the ajax split-screen disappears. But the page that I linked on the jquery does nothing.

Some code is in Dutch so ask if you need translation.

My code is as follows:
Page users.php

```
<script>
  function jsAjaxVieuwUser(str) {

    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("mainRight").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    } else {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("mainRight").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxBeheer.php?VieuwUser=" + str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();

      document.getElementById("mainRight").style = "display: inline-block;"; // Don`t show the start table
      document.getElementById("closeUser").style = "display: block;"; // Don`t show the start table
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="main">
    <div class="mainInfo">
        <h3>Gebruikers</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="mainContent">

        <div class="mainLeft" id="mainLeft">
            <div class="actionBar">
                <div><a href="newuser.php"><button class="button button2">Nieuwe gebruiker</button></a></div>
                <div id="closeUser"><a href="#" onClick="closeUserVieuw()"><button class="button button2"> &#60;&#60; </button></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="list" id="userList">
                <ul>
                    <li class="listheader"><div class="listFirstColum">Naam gebruiker</div> <div class="listSecondColum">Laatste login</div></li>
    <?php
                    if(!isset($_GET['limit'])){
                        //     START, AANTAL
                        $limit = '0 , 10';
                    }
                    $result = $db->select("SELECT ID, user_name, user_last_login FROM users ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT ".$limit." ",array(''),array(''));

                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<a href="#" onClick="jsAjaxVieuwUser('.$row['ID'].')"><li> <div class="listFirstColum">'.$row['user_name'].'</div> <div class="listSecondColum">'.$row['user_last_login'].'</div> </li></a>';
                    }

    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mainRight" id="mainRight">
            <h1>HALLO</h1>
        </div>

    </div>




</div>
```

Page ajaxBeheer.php

```
if(isset($_GET['VieuwUser'])){

    $disabled = 'disabled';
    $idUser = $_GET['VieuwUser'];

    $result = $db->select(" SELECT  users.ID, 
                                    users.user_name, 
                                    users.user_email, 
                                    userinfo.userid, 
                                    userinfo.user_firstname, 
                                    userinfo.user_lastname, 
                                    userinfo.user_birthday, 
                                    userinfo.user_adress, 
                                    userinfo.user_adressnr

                            FROM users INNER JOIN userinfo 
                            ON userinfo.userid = users.ID 
                            WHERE users.ID=? ", array($idUser),array('%i'));

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Gebruikers gegevens   
        $username = $row['user_name'];
        $user_email = $row['user_email'];

    //Personal data
        $user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
        $user_lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
        $user_birthday = $row['user_birthday'];
        $user_adress = $row['user_adress'];
        $user_adressnr = $row['user_adressnr'];

    }

    // make the date readable, but if its empty make it 0000
    if ($user_birthday == '0000-00-00' || empty($user_birthday)) {
        $user_birthday = ' ';
    }else{
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $user_birthday);
        $user_birthday = $date->format('d-m-Y');
    }

        ?>
        <div class="contentHolder" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="header">
                    <h3 style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">Gegevens medewerker: <?= $username ?></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="prLeftColomn colomn">
                    <form name="gebruiker" id="formId" method="POST">
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Voornaam</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?= $user_firstname ?>" /></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Achternaam</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?= $user_lastname ?>" /></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Email</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?= $user_email ?>" /></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Geboorte datum</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?= $user_birthday ?>" /></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Telefoon</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" /></div></p>

                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Adres + huisnummer</div><div class="waarde">&nbsp;<?= $user_adress.'&nbsp;'.$user_adressnr ?></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Postcode</div><div class="waarde">&nbsp;</div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Plaats</div><div class="waarde">&nbsp;</div></p>
                        <p><div><input class="button" type="submit" name="updateGebruiker" value="UPDATE" onclick="save()"/></div></p>
                    </form>
                </div>              

<style type="javascript">
function save(){
        var query = $('#formId').serialize();
        var url = 'updateUser.php';
        $.post(url, query, function (response) {
         alert (response);
        });

    }
</style>
```

page updateUser.php

```
<?php

    $table = 'userinfo';
    $data = array('user_firstname' => 'test'); 
    $format = array('%s');
    $where = array('id' => '3');
    $where_format = array('%i');
    $updateCalc = $db->update($table, $data, $format, $where, $where_format);
?>
```

Comment: Did you check my solution? comment me if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of refreshing the page is because you're using a form with submit button, to prevent it just prevent the form to submit

if you have Jquery use the following

```
//option A
$("form#formId").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and Pure js solution is

```
document.getElementById('formId').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I have tryed it and yea the page doesn`t refresh anymore. But the page execute doesn`t work. I did go back to the basics and minimalize everything and still it doen`t work. If i opened the updateUser.php it worked, so that script is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok have it finally worked. Had the jquery in the ajaxBeheer.php script. Now i have it in the page where the ajax is executed. And that worked for me.
The Jquery link

Is located in the header.

I have now a second screen where the information is updated without a refresh page. :D
It`s without security so thats need too update for everyone that wants too use it! The question was for the second screen no refresh page.

Hopefully i can help some other people with it, becease it was a pain for me too find information.

The whole code:
Page users.php:

```
<?php
    require_once (__DIR__.'/safeuser.php');
    require_once (__DIR__.'/include/topheader.php');
    require_once (__DIR__.'/include/config.inc.php');
    require_once (__DIR__.'/classes/class-db.php');

?>


<script>
  function jsAjaxVieuwUser(str) {

        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("mainRight").innerHTML = "";

            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("mainRight").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxBeheer.php?VieuwUser=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            document.getElementById("mainRight").style = "display: inline-block;"; // Don`t show the start table
            document.getElementById("closeUser").style = "display: block;"; // Don`t show the start table
        }
  }


function save(){
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#formId');

    // Get the messages div. Too show the messages on screen
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // TODO: The rest of the code will go here...
    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(event) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        event.preventDefault();

        // TODO
        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })

        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            alert (response);
        })

        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });
    });
}

function closeUserVieuw() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mainRight");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("closeUser").style = "display: none;"; // Don`t show the start table
    }
}

</script>


<style type="text/css">


</style>


<div class="main">
    <div class="mainInfo">
        <h3>Gebruikers</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="mainContent">

        <div class="mainLeft" id="mainLeft">
            <div class="actionBar">
                <div><a href="newuser.php"><button class="button button2">Nieuwe gebruiker</button></a></div>
                <div id="closeUser"><a href="#" onClick="closeUserVieuw()"><button class="button button2"> &#60;&#60; </button></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="list" id="userList">
                <ul>
                    <li class="listheader"><div class="listFirstColum">Naam gebruiker</div> <div class="listSecondColum">Laatste login</div></li>
    <?php
                    if(!isset($_GET['limit'])){
                        //     START, AANTAL
                        $limit = '0 , 10';
                    }
                    $result = $db->select("SELECT ID, user_name, user_last_login FROM users ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT ".$limit." ",array(''),array(''));

                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<a href="#" onClick="jsAjaxVieuwUser('.$row['ID'].')"><li> <div class="listFirstColum">'.$row['user_name'].'</div> <div class="listSecondColum">'.$row['user_last_login'].'</div> </li></a>';
                    }

    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mainRight" id="mainRight">
            <h1>HALLO</h1>
        </div>

    </div>




</div>




<!-- FOOTER -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

ajaxBeheer.php:

```
<?php
    // name: ajaxBeheer.php

    require_once (__DIR__.'/classes/class-users.php');
    require_once (__DIR__.'/include/config.inc.php');

if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    $zoek = $_GET['q'];
    $param = "$zoek%"; // Zoek alleen op voorletter
    $getGebruiker = $db->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE naam LIKE ?",array($param),array('s'));

?>

    <div id="tableUsers">
            <div class="headRow" style="" id="tableUsers">
                <div class="cell" style="width: 70%">Gebruiker</div>
                <div class="cell" style="width: 30%; border-left: 2px solid #fff; border-right: 2px solid #fff;">Status</div>
            </div>

            <?php
            while ($myrow = $getGebruiker->fetch_assoc()) {

                if($myrow['active'] == '1'){
                    $gebrActive = 'Aktief';
                } else {
                    $gebrActive = 'gedeaktiveerd';
                }

                echo '<a style="display:block" href="?ID='.$myrow['id'].'">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="cell" style="width: 70%">'.$myrow['naam'].'</div>
                            <div class="cell" style="width: 30%; border-left: 1px solid #fff; border-right: 1px solid #fff;">'.$gebrActive.'</div>
                        </div></a>';

            }
            echo '</div>';
}


if(isset($_GET['VieuwUser'])){

    $disabled = 'disabled';
    $idUser = $_GET['VieuwUser'];

    $result = $db->select(" SELECT  users.ID, 
                                    users.user_name, 
                                    users.user_email, 
                                    userinfo.userid, 
                                    userinfo.user_firstname, 
                                    userinfo.user_lastname, 
                                    userinfo.user_birthday, 
                                    userinfo.user_adress, 
                                    userinfo.user_adressnr

                            FROM users INNER JOIN userinfo 
                            ON userinfo.userid = users.ID 
                            WHERE users.ID=? ", array($idUser),array('%i'));

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Gebruikers gegevens   
        $username = $row['user_name'];
        $user_email = $row['user_email'];

    //Personal data
        $user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
        $user_lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
        $user_birthday = $row['user_birthday'];
        $user_adress = $row['user_adress'];
        $user_adressnr = $row['user_adressnr'];

    }

    // make the date readable, but if its empty make it 0000
    if ($user_birthday == '0000-00-00' || empty($user_birthday)) {
        $user_birthday = ' ';
    }else{
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $user_birthday);
        $user_birthday = $date->format('d-m-Y');
    }

        ?>


        <div class="contentHolder" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="header">
                    <h3 style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">Gegevens medewerker: <?= $username ?></h3>
                </div>


                <div class="prLeftColomn colomn">
                    <form name="gebruiker" id="formId" action="updateUser.php">
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Voornaam</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?= $user_firstname ?>" /></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Achternaam</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?= $user_lastname ?>" /></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Email</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="useremail" value="<?= $user_email ?>" /></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Geboorte datum</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="userbirthday" value="<?= $user_birthday ?>" /></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Telefoon</div><div class="waarde"><input type="text" name="usertel" value="" /></div></p>

                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Adres + huisnummer</div><div class="waarde">&nbsp;<?= $user_adress.'&nbsp;'.$user_adressnr ?></div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Postcode</div><div class="waarde">&nbsp;</div></p>
                        <p><div class="omschrijving">Plaats</div><div class="waarde">&nbsp;</div></p>
                        <p><div><input class="button" type="submit" name="updateGebruiker" value="UPDATE" onclick="save()"/></div></p>
                    </form>
                </div>              



                <div class="header" style="margin-top: 5%">
                    <h3 style="width: 90%; text-align: center;">Uren overzicht</h3>
                </div>

                <div id="tableUserUren">
                    <div class="prLeftColomn colomn">

                        <label>Uren deze week</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" style="background: white;" <?= $disabled ?> />
                        <label>Uren deze maand</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" style="background: white;" <?= $disabled ?> />
                        <label>Uren vorige maand</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" style="background: white;" <?= $disabled ?> />
                        <label>Uren Vrij genomen</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" style="background: white;" <?= $disabled ?> />
                        <label></label>
                            <input type="text" value="" style="background: white;" <?= $disabled ?> />
                    </div>

                    <div class="prRightColomn colomn">

                    </div>  
                </div>

        </div>

        <?php

}
?>
```

updateUser.php

```
<?php
    require_once (__DIR__.'/include/config.inc.php');
    require_once (__DIR__.'/classes/class-db.php');


            $username = $_POST['firstname'];


            // Ready too add the username
            $table = 'users';
            $data = array('user_name' => $username); 
            $format = array('%s');
            $newJob = $db->insert($table, $data, $format);

            if($newJob != $db::SQLSUCCESFULL){ // Variable is 00000
                echo 'Er is helaas iets fout gegaan met het toevoegen van de regel. Code:'.$newJob;
                header('location: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'].'newuser.php?err=DATABASE&code='.$newJob);
                exit();

            }else{
                echo 'succes!'.$username;
            }

?>
```